# Accessing pasted picture in Excel VBA module

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to the world of VB and I'm currently copying + pasting parts of my spreed sheet like this:

```
Sheets("Overview").Range("G4:P34").CopyPicture
Sheets("Overview").Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Overview").Range("T4")
```

So basically I'm just copying the area from **G4** to **P34** as an image and paste it starting at **T4** which works fine so far. The thing is the newly created picture gets an automatically assigned `Name` attribute so I can't access it as simple as the following snippet, because I actually don't know its name:

```
Sheets("Overview").Shapes("Picture xx").DoSomethingWithIt
```

My question is how can I access the picture I just pasted into my sheet? Any advice would be appreciated, many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you need is Application.Caller Property which returns what was called. An example is

```
    sub pic()
    ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).Select
     'some code

    End Sub
```

This should select the last object(picture) without you having to remember its name. Here you can more about it

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193687(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: in fact, after a paste, the picture is automatically already selected. Also, to use application.calle, correctly, you have to call it somehow (clic on picture with macro attached to it...)